# Questions on conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

After conditional formatting the entire column, some cells are filled with the chosen color. But what can I do if I want the entire row to be colored (not just the cell being formatted), as now I need to manually select each cell 1-by-1 and highlight the entire row?

Also, after all the rows that are conditionally formatted, are there any ways to automatically copy and paste them into a new worksheet?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic conditional formatting (CF) (e.g. cell value above or below a threshold) works only on its own cell value. If you want to format say the whole row from B2 to F2 based on  the value in A2, you must create a new CF rule. Select the row, and select new CF option "from formula" and use say `=$A2>10`. Note the use of the $ which will lock the column number in but let the row number adjust relatively as you copy and paste the formatting downwards.

To copy to a new sheet automatically, you would need to code a VBA macro that does the copying if you push a button or a user defined shortcut key. Alternatively, consider adding an autofilter, and filter the data against the same criteria as the CF. Now press ctrl+A to select all, ctrl+c to copy, select a new sheet, ctrl+v to paste. (Immediately press ctrl to pop up the paste menu, press V for paste as value - the last step only required if you need to free the data from formulae that has become invalid in the new sheet).